# How do I find the values of the constants for which $y = ax + b +e^{cx}$ is a solution to the differential equation given.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Let
>   $$y'=3x+2y+1$$
>   Find the constants $a,b,c$ for which $y=ax+b+e^{cx}$ is a solution to the differential equation

So, I know how to solve differential equations, but I'm stuck on how to start this problem. Can anyone show me how I can start this question? I thought that maybe I could start off by moving $2y$ to the other side, but I'm not sure if that is the right way to start this question.

Comment: With the form given, plug in everything and simplify. You should then be able to match coefficients.

Comment: What do you mean by plug in everything?

Comment: Don't change the solution please

Comment: As an unrelated example, suppose $A e^{fx}+B \cos(x)=e^{3x}+2\cos(x)$. Then $A=1, f=3, B=2$. This is what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You have 
$$y'=3x+2y+1$$
You are given the solution
$$y=ax+b+e^{cx}$$
Differentitate you get
$$y'=a+ce^{cx}$$
Plug $y'$ and $y$ in the differential equation to get $a,b$ and $c$  values.
$$y'=3x+2y+1$$
$$a+ce^{cx}=3x+2(ax+b+e^{cx})+1$$
$$x(3+2a)+(2b+1-a)+e^{cx}(2-c)=0$$

This must hold for all $x$. 
$$ \implies
\begin {cases}
 3+2a=0 \\ 2b+1-a=0 \\2-c=0
\end{cases}
$$
Solve this system of equations.

Comment: Shouldn't the cs be a cx?

Comment: Ok, so I understand how you got up to this point, but I don't understand how I can get the values for constants a and b. Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe that the value of constant c is 2.

Comment: @P1081  yes true and $a=-3/2$ collext all the terms taht are constants and all the terms that are coefficents of x and so on The equality must hold for all x so the coeffients are all zero

Comment: Ok, I think I almost got it! I just have one question: How did you know a = -3/2?

Comment: All the coefficents must be zero @P1081 I added a line and you will also get that $b=-5/4$

Comment: I see, so would b = -5/4?

Comment: @P1081 Yes that's correct